# Can I get a page screenshot from within a mocha/phantomjs unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm using grunt-mocha to run unit tests via phantomJS.

I know that phantomJS has a lot of useful functionality. Can I access that from within a mocha test?

I've looked in the obvious places such as the `window` object to see if I can somehow access the page object, but nothing seems obvious.

Specifically, I'd like to render a screenshot of the page under test.

Answer (score 1):

This is called ["Screen Capture" in the documentation](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture).

The important part is that you need a reference to the `WebPage`, not the browser `window` object (this just emulates what JavaScript can usually see from inside the browser).

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function () {
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not creating the page.. the test code is running on the page. Is it possible to work back from the script to the page object, or access it via mocha?

Comment: Maybe. Do you need screenshots during while a test runs or once after each test to see the final output?

Comment: Ideally during, but afterwards would also be useful

Comment: Did you see the [bridge.js](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha/blob/master/phantomjs/bridge.js)? It can publish events from mocha to phantomjs. On the phantom side, you can use `onAlert` to make screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

I have forked and added screenshotting support to grunt-mocha. See the "Screenshotting" section in https://github.com/bjfletcher/grunt-mocha.

This will hopefully be pulled into Kelly's grunt-mocha and eventually npmjs.org: https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha/pull/109